# Cucumber JVM - How to re-use method written in other Feature Class correctly?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have 2 features files (`FeatureA` and `FeatureB`). The first 2 steps in those feature files are exactly the same, so I want to write the implementation once only and then can be re-used by other feature files.

```js
Feature A 

Given I use "<browser>"
When I navigate to the "www.google.com"
Then I will be able to do A
```

```js
Feature B

Given I use "<browser>"
When I navigate to the "www.google.com"
Then I will be able to do B
```

I have parent class `Base`

```js
public class Base {

  public LandingPage landingPage;

  public synchronized void initiate(String browser) {

    // Do usual Chrome / Firefox WebDriver instantiation 

    this.landingPage = new LandingPage(); // Instantiate landingPage
  }

  public synchronized void navigateTo(String URL, Scenario scenario) throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get(URL);
  }
}
```

I implement the `Feature A` below

```js
public class FeatureA extends Base {

  @Given("I use {string}")
  public void i_use(String browser) {
    initiate(browser, scenario); // Call the method in parent class Base. This should instantiate this.landingPage = new LandingPage();
  }

  @When("I navigate to the {string}")
  public void i_navigate_to_the(String URL) throws InterruptedException {
    navigateTo(URL, scenario);
  }

  @Then("Then I will be able to do A")
  public void then_i_will_be_able_to_do_A() {
    //Do something specific to Feature A only
  }
}
```

I implement `Feature B` below. (I am re-using step 1 and step 2 in `Feature A`, so won't need to duplicate it in `Feature B`)

```js
public class FeatureB extends Base {

  @Then("Then I will be able to do B")
  public void then_i_will_be_able_to_do_B() {
    //Do something specific to Feature B only

    log.debug("landingpage : " + super.landingPage); // Null.  Not sure why? 
  }
}
```

When I run `Feature A` gherkin file, all good.

When I run `Feature B` gherkin file, the variable / reference `super.landingPage` returns me `null`.

I run debug mode and I can see `initiate(browser, scenario);` has been invoked, hence `public LandingPage landingPage;` has been instantiated by other Class (`Class FeatureA`), **before** the step in `Feature B` is executed. But `Class FeatureB` sees `null`

So, how do I use the method sitting in Feature A and re-use it in Feature B , C, D ?

Comment: inheritance, composition, ... Seeing as in this case there is a common parent class, why not use the code to reuse to the Base class?

Comment: A base class would be the wrong idea. Then you end up with multiple instances of what ever is in the base class. In essence you'd share the methods, but not the state. In this case you'd also want to share the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with dependency injection. Dependency injection allows you to compose your step definitions of smaller components that can be injected via the constructor of other components.

The easiest to get started with is with `cucumber-picocontainer`.

```xml
<dependencies>
  [...]
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  [...]
</dependencies>
```

```java
public class WebDriverContainer {

   private final Webdriver delegate;

   // Create webdriver instance here
   // as needed by invoking a method from your step definitions.
   // or something more advanced: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/picocontainer#step-scope-and-lifecycle

   // note that before and after hooks can also be used here to do the clean up/setup.
}
public class FeatureA {

  private WebDriverContainer webdriver;

  public FeatureA(WebDriverContainer webdriver){
      this.webdriver = webdriver;
  }
  
  // Use webdriver container in your steps

}
public class FeatureB {

  private WebDriverContainer webdriver;

  public FeatureB(WebDriverContainer webdriver){
      this.webdriver = webdriver;
  }
  
  // Use webdriver container in your steps

}
```

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/picocontainer